# How to fill a Spinner from an array of arrays

Tags: android, arrays, spinner

This is the error that i'm receiving.

Null Pointer Exception
11-06 19:03:34.050: WARN/System.err(5342):     at RetrievingAmazonXMLDataActivity.onCreate(RetrievingAmazonXMLDataActivity.java:88)

```
    for (int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) {
                String a = dumpTitles("ProductName", i);
                element = a.split("!");
                allProducts.add(element);
            }

           w =  (String[][])allProducts.toArray(new String[allProducts.size()][]);


    Spinner spinnerProducts = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
            spinnerProducts.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

// **** error line below


     ArrayAdapter<String> productsArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, productArrayToShow);

           productsArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            spinnerProducts.setAdapter(productsArrayAdapter);

     public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id)
        {

            try {
                selected = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();


                productArrayToShow = w[position];

            } catch (Exception e) {}
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't really say what "productArrayToShow" is in your code, but I'm going to assume it's a 2D array of strings that you want to display in the adapter. Easiest way is to just make a 1D array out of it:

```
int rows = productArrayToShow.length;
int cols = productArrayToShow[0].length;
String[] productArray = new String[rows*cols];
int count = 0;
for(int r=0; r<rows; ++r)
  for(int c=0; c<cols; ++c)
    productArray[count++] = productArrayToShow[r][c];
```